# Draw hough transform lines over an image

Tags: python, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am trying to implement **Hough line transform** by myself, but I just couldn't do the last step which is drawing high voted thetas/rhos values. I tried to do its math on my own but It remained to get wrong outputs. When I checked some implementations of others, they were always using this approach to transform from **Polar** to **cartesian** coordinates in order to find two points.

```
for r,theta in lines[0]: 

# Stores the value of cos(theta) in a 
a = np.cos(theta) 

# Stores the value of sin(theta) in b 
b = np.sin(theta) 

# x0 stores the value rcos(theta) 
x0 = a*r 

# y0 stores the value rsin(theta) 
y0 = b*r 

# x1 stores the rounded off value of (rcos(theta)-1000sin(theta)) 
x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b)) 

# y1 stores the rounded off value of (rsin(theta)+1000cos(theta)) 
y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a)) 

# x2 stores the rounded off value of (rcos(theta)+1000sin(theta)) 
x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b)) 

# y2 stores the rounded off value of (rsin(theta)-1000cos(theta)) 
y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a)) 

# cv2.line draws a line in img from the point(x1,y1) to (x2,y2). 
# (0,0,255) denotes the colour of the line to be  
#drawn. In this case, it is red.  
cv2.line(img,(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,255),2)
```

The previous code from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/line-detection-python-opencv-houghline-method/).
What I didn't get are those equations `x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))` & `y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))`. By translating these equations as a mathematic form : **x1 = r cos(theta) + r (-sin(theta))**||
**y1 = r sin(theta) + r (cos(theta))**

These two equations are just strange to me. 'r cos(theta)' is normal as we transfer from polar to cartesian. However, the next part isn't clear. Could anyone explain the original math behind it?

Comment: I'm not sure about your math, but why are you multiplying everything by 1000?

Comment: No .. no, I already implemented it by another equation. I just wanted to understand the implementation above as it has been used by almost hough line implementations [just like the link I've mentioned above]. 
Also, I wrote this code as it's, and then it worked as well. That's why I am so confused about its math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(r cos, r sin) is the point closest to the origin on the line. It is not a line equation. To draw a line, u need 2 points. Here, he just moved along line 1000 and -1000 to get two points that are guaranteed to be outside a medium sized image

There are many ways to get line equation. Easiest is:
    r = x cos + y sin

```
If x1 = x - t sin
y1 = (1 / sin) (r - x cos + t sin cos)
= y + t cos
```

He used t=+/-1000 for image size

Comment: Um, i am asking about the drive of these two equations !! X1= x - t sin !! And the same for y.

Comment: It is a line equation. U substitute x by x + t and compute y. Varying t gives different points on the line. Here, t used is - t sin for convenience. But you can t and drive the two points in the same way

Comment: Also, x0, x1, x2, y0, y1, y2 here are constants. The only random variable is t

Comment: I still didn't get it !!! 
yes, I know that using t = +/- 1000 to ensure that the line is drawn over the image. However, why we substitute x by x+t !!! 
I just wanna understand its math behind that's all. logically it's math kinda weird as there's no prove(drive) from the line equation ` r = x cos + y sin` and `x1 = x0 + r sin` | `y1 = y0 + r cos`. I mean the term `r sin` if we observed it over the graph we would just add a part of y-coordinate to the value of x0 point and vice versa for the y0 point. that's why I can't understand this part.

Comment: r sin here has nothing to do with y. Let’s start from line equation: r = x cos + y sin. Here, u can substitute a value for x and compute y for a point on the line. Right? Let’s substitute x by (r cos - t sin). We get y = (r - r cos2 + t sin cos) / sin = (r sin2 + r cos2 - r cos2 + t sin cos) / sin = r sin + t cos. Right?